# Strip Comments Function

Tags: c++, fstream

It is giving me an error when I am calling the file in the function, the file is a cpp file, forget about the algorithm, my problem is why is it giving me an error when calling the cpp file in the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void stripComment(ifstream &comm)
{
    string line;
    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;
    inStream.open("comm.cpp");
    while (comm)
    {
        cin >> line;
    }
    cout << line;
    inStream.close();
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;
    stripComment("comm.cpp");
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include the compiler messages you get.  `stripComment` wants an `ifstream &`, but you're passing it a `const char *`.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default constructing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case that means changing `ifstream inStream; inStream.open(“comm.cpp”);` to `ifstream inStream(“comm.cpp”);`. And you don’t need to call `inStream.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: When stripping comments, be aware of some outlier cases: 1) `"/*"` - A starting C-Style comment in double quotes (doesn't start a comment). 2) `"//"` Same, using C++ comments. 3) Line continuation characters: `// me \\`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your compiler, it will tell you exactly what the problem is:

```cpp
In function 'int main()':
23:18: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::ifstream&' {aka 
'std::basic_ifstream<char>&'} from expression of type 'const char [9]'
   23 |     stripComment("comm.cpp");
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What the compiler is telling you there is that the type that `stripComment` expects is `std::ifstream&` but you are giving it a `const char*` which is not convertible to `std::ifstream&` that's why it won't compile. All you need to do is change the parameter type to be `const char*` or `const std::string&` and it will then have different problems (related to your algorithm).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void stripComment(const std::string &comm)
{
    string line;
    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;
    inStream.open("comm.cpp");
    while (comm)
    {
        cin >> line;
    }
    cout << line;
    inStream.close();
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inStream;
    ofstream outStream;
    stripComment("comm.cpp");
}
```

```
In function 'void stripComment(const string&)':
11:12: error: could not convert 'comm' from 'const string' {aka 'const 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'bool'
   11 |     while (comm)
      |            ^~~~
      |            |
      |            const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
```

That one still won't compile, though, because now you are using a `const std::string&` as though it was a `bool`. Once again, a `std::string` is not convertible to a `bool`, so just switch the `comm` for the `inStream` and put the `comm` in the `inStream` constructor to open that file. Now everything works (I also deleted the extra stuff):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void stripComment(const std::string &comm)
{
    string line;
    ifstream inStream(comm);
    while (inStream)
    {
        cin >> line;
    }
    cout << line;
}

int main()
{
    stripComment("comm.cpp");
    return 0;
}
```

Now it will compile fine. It will probably not do what you want, though. `while (inStream){...}` is going to be an infinite loop if `comm.cpp` exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i didn't need to use a file as parameter, i could've simply taken a string as name, and then used infile.open to open that specific file and that is it.